# How does one do a null check for a Guid in xslt?

Tags: xslt, comparison, guid, nullable

I am trying to edit an xslt file.
One line reads:

```
<xsl:if test="number(./@LatestAuthor) &gt; 0">
```

The issue I have is that latest author used to be of type int and is now a nullable Guid.  How can I edit the xslt file to check if @LatestAuthor is not null? Thanks.

Comment: how does you xml with a null Guid look like? Is it ... LatestAuthor="null" ... or LatestAuthor="" ... or does the attribute LatestAuthor not exist?

Answer (score 1):

- If you just want to test to see whether there is a `@LatestAuthor` attribute(with or without a value) use this: `<xsl:if test="@LatestAuthor">`
- If you want to test to see whether `@LatestAuthor` exists **AND** has a value, you can use this: `<xsl:if test="@LatestAuthor[.!='']">`
- If you want to test to see whether `@LatestAuthor` is present **AND** has a non-whitespace value, you can use this: `<xsl:if test="@LatestAuthor[normalize-space()!='']">`
- If you want to test to see whether `@LatestAuthor` is present **AND** has a numeric value, you can use this: `<xsl:if test="@LatestAuthor[number()]">`